# Normalize rows of a matrix within range 0 and 1

Tags: r, matrix, row

I am trying to normalize all rows of my matrix data at once within range 0 and 1. But I don't know how to do it..
For example, I want to normalize each "obs1", "obs2", "obs3". Thus, minimum, maximum, and sum of each "obs1", "obs2", "obs3" will be used. 
My data format is,

`mydata

```
             a        b        c         d         e
obs1   8.15609  11.5379  11.1401   8.95186   7.95722
obs2 339.89800 856.3470 691.3490 590.28600 543.67200
obs3   2.12776  46.4561 136.8860 118.09100 119.86400
```

`

Also, When I searched to perform this, people used "function()". When/for what does this used?

Thank you very much for your help in advance! :)

Comment: Rather an un-statistical use of the word "normalize". This transformation has nothing at all to do with the Normal distribution (and nothing to do with any of the various meanings listed in Wikipedia.) A phrase that might be more accurate would be "unit mapping" or "scale to the unit interval".

Answer (score 30):

To normalize for each row, you can use `apply` and then subtract the minimum from each column and divide by the difference between maximum and minimum:

```
t(apply(mydata, 1, function(x)(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))))
```

gives you

```
              a         b         c         d         e
obs1 0.05553973 1.0000000 0.8889038 0.2777796 0.0000000
obs2 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.6805144 0.4848262 0.3945675
obs3 0.00000000 0.3289472 1.0000000 0.8605280 0.8736849
```

What happens is that you apply the function

```
function(x){
   (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
}
```

to each row of your data frame.

Comment: THank you very much. It seems that you changed a value from "2" to "1" in function apply. It helps a lot :)

Comment: The "1" is the `MARGIN` argument. Look at `?apply` for explanation.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`apply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/apply) with [`rescale`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/rescale) as the following:

```
apply(mydata, 1, rescale)
```

where the second argument `1` tells apply to work with rows.

The default range is [0, 1] but a custom range can be specified with the `to` argument that will be forwarded to the `rescale` function:

```
apply(mydata, 1, rescale, to=c(1,2))
```

Dependecy:

```
if(!require(scales)){
    install.packages("scales", dependencies=TRUE)
    library(scales)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in 2:length(mydata[1,])){

    mydata[,i] <- prop.table(mydata[,i])

}
```

Normalized matrix will be updated in mydata